# Best practise for video ground truthing?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning, object-detection, video-processing

I would like to train a deep learning framework (TensorFlow) for object detection with a new object category.

As source for the ground truthing I have multiple video files which contain the object (only part of the image contains the object).

How should I ground truth the video? Should I extract frame by frame and label every frame even when those video frames will be quite similar? Or what would be best practise for such a task?

Open source tools are preferred.

Answer (score 0):

It usually works as you described. At lest for the **iteration zero**:

1. collect required examples (video)
2. extract valuable frames from the video (manual or partially automated process)
3. use OpenCV (or any other tool) to extract required details (bounding box, accurate mask)
4. assemble a training set
5. train a model

Here is an example of a training set, produced by the approach described above ([see it in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1xhBlYEPfo))

[image]

For **iteration one** you might use iteration zero models and significantly improve step 2 and step 3 to increase the training set even more.

I'm trying to solve pretty much the same problem, because it is hard to produce a training set to get accurate segmentation:

[image]

(again, [here it is in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NAIYz2Y4Dz4) and [other examples](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLsVHuYpywKFNAHKFfImIVg/videos))

Basically, start with a semi-manual approach and try to evolve.