# Is same-location pictures good enough to train an object detection model?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I'm currently working on a custom object detection for which I need to gather data (labeled images of the object).
The object is rare enough that I only managed to find around 50 distinct pictures of it on google images, but there are a couple of two-minutes videos that I downloaded and saved every frame of them as a distinct picture(which amount to over 9000 (not a meme) images).
Is this a good approach or not ?

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely a good approach, especially in case of rare objects. There are not so many other ways to create high-quality training set. Check additional details here:

- [How to prepare training data for image segmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58953890/1435741)
- [Best practice for video ground truthing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58916262/1435741)

Another great example demonstrates you can get great results with basic equipment and a tiny piece of creativity:

[image]

([see the video](https://youtu.be/RNnKtNrsrmg))

You just have to make sure:

- videos are different to avoid overfitting
- it is not a problem to annotate huge amount of images
- more data can be added in case results are not that good
- you can automate at least some steps

I've been busy developing training set generation solution for quite some time (see [some examples](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLsVHuYpywKFNAHKFfImIVg/videos)) and see no other way but to create a fully or semi automated solution based on video.

[image]

(see [the complete set](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1xhBlYEPfo))